# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_expandendnoevents' of undefined

Tags: json.net

i am trying to rebind data to ighierarchicalgrid on rowexpanding event and it is throwing error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_expandendnoevents' of undefined". when i will give initialExpandDepth as 1 that time data is binding. if i remove it it is throwing above error.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("DataStoreData", "DataStore")',
            data: JSON.stringify(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                treegriddata = result;
                igGridLoading(treegriddata);
                collapseAllRows($("#hierarchicalGrid"));
            }
        });
});
function collapseAllRows(rootGrid) {
        var level = 1, children, id, ad;
        ad = rootGrid.igHierarchicalGrid("option", "animationDuration");
        rootGrid.igHierarchicalGrid("option", "animationDuration", 0);
        $(rootGrid.igGrid("allRows")).each(function (index, element) {
            rootGrid.igHierarchicalGrid("collapse", element);
        });

    id = setInterval(function () {
        children = rootGrid.igHierarchicalGrid("allChildren").filter("table[data-level='" + level + "']");
        if (children.length > 0) {
            $(children).each(function (index, element) {

                $($(element).igGrid("allRows")).each(function (index, element) {
                    if ($(element).find("td.ui-iggrid-expandcolumn").length > 0 && ($(element).attr("state") === undefined || $(element).attr("state") === "c")) {
                        rootGrid.igHierarchicalGrid("collapse", element);
                    }
                });
            });
            level++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(id);
            rootGrid.igHierarchicalGrid("option", "animationDuration", ad);
        }
    }, 1000);

}

function igGridLoading(data) {
    $("#hierarchicalGrid").igHierarchicalGrid({
        width: "100%",
        autoGenerateColumns: false,
        dataSource: data,
        autoCommit: true,
        primaryKey: "ProjectId",
        dataSourceType: "json",
        autoGenerateLayots: false,
        initialExpandDepth: 1,
        columns: [
            { headerText: "Project Id", key: "ProjectId", dataType: "number", width: "0%", hidden: true },
            { headerText: "Project Ref", key: "ProjectRef", dataType: "string", width: "15%" },
            { headerText: "Project Desc", key: "ProjectDesc", dataType: "string", width: "20%" }
        ],
        childrenDataProperty: "Process",
        autoGenerateLayouts: false,
        columnLayouts: [
            {
                key: "Process",
                autoCommit: true,
                //responseDataKey: "results",
                autoGenerateColumns: false,
                autofitLastColumn: false,
                primaryKey: "ProjProcId",
                width: "100%",
                columns: [
                    { headerText: "Project Process Id", key: "ProjProcId", dataType: "number", width: "100px", hidden: true },
                    { headerText: "Process Code", key: "ProcessCode", dataType: "string", width: "100px" },
                    { headerText: "Process Name", key: "ProcessName", dataType: "string", width: "150px" }
                ],
                features: [
                    {
                        name: "Paging",
                        pageSize: 10
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Selection",
                        mode: "row",
                        multipleSelection: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Sorting",
                        type: "local"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Filtering",
                        type: "local"
                    }
                ],
                childrenDataProperty: "Components",
                autoGenerateLayouts: false,
                columnLayouts: [
                    {
                        key: "Components",
                        autoCommit: true,
                        //responseDataKey: "results",
                        autoGenerateColumns: false,
                        autofitLastColumn: false,
                        primaryKey: "ProcCompId",
                        width: "100%",
                        columns: [
                            { headerText: "Process Component Id", key: "ProcCompId", dataType: "number", width: "100px", hidden: true },
                            { headerText: "Component Code", key: "ComponentCode", dataType: "string", width: "120px" },
                            { headerText: "Component Desc", key: "ComponentDesc", dataType: "string", width: "150px" },
                            { headerText: "Component Value", key: "ComponentValue", dataType: "string", width: "150px" }
                        ],
                        features: [
                            {
                                name: "Paging",
                                pageSize: 10
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Selection",
                                mode: "row",
                                multipleSelection: true
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Sorting",
                                type: "local"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Filtering",
                                type: "local"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        rowExpanding: function (e, args) {
            var grid = args.owner, expandedRows, i;
            expandedRows = $(args.parentrow).closest('tbody').find('tr[state=e]');
            for (i = 0; i < expandedRows.length; i++) {
                grid.collapse(expandedRows[i]);
            }
            var childGrid = args.parentrow.next().find("table.ui-iggrid-table");
            //args.owner.element.parents("tr[data-container='true']").prevObject[0].rows['2'].parentNode.hidden = true;
            var id = $(childGrid).attr("id");
            var rows = $('#' + id).igGrid("rows");
            if (rows.length === 0) {
                $(args.parentrow.find("span")[0]).hide();
                $('#' + id).hide();
            }
        },
        features: [
            {
                name: 'Selection',
                mode: 'row',
                multipleSelection: false,
                activation: true
            }
        ],
        rowExpanded: function (e, args) {
            alert(e + args);
        }
    });

    $("#hierarchicalGrid").igHierarchicalGrid("dataBind");
    $("#hierarchicalGrid").on("ighierarchicalgridrowexpanding", function (evt, ui) {
        var message = "ighierarchicalgridrowexpanding";
        alert(message);
        index = ui.parentrow.attr("data-id");
        loadChildGridData(index);
    });
}

function loadChildGridData(index) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/DataStore/DataStoreProcessData?key=' + index,
        data: JSON.stringify(),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var comp = treegriddata[index - 1].Process[0].Components;
            treegriddata[index - 1].Process = result;
            for (var i = 0; i < treegriddata[index - 1].Process.length; i++) {
                treegriddata[index - 1].Process[i].Components = comp;
            }
            //Initialize
            $("#hierarchicalGrid").igHierarchicalGrid({
                initialDataBindDepth: 1
            });
            igGridLoading(treegriddata);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: please share your code and tag the language.

Comment: Also, please include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the traceback.